# How can I re-establish a previously closed gRPC stream in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, grpc

I have a unary gRPC server to client notification stream that I would like to close and open again from client-side.

Following along [this article](https://laurentkempe.com/2019/09/25/gRPC-and-csharp-8-Async-stream-cancellation/) and the [Reliable gRPC services with deadlines and cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/deadlines-cancellation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) article from the MS Docs I hold the call and a cancellation token for the stream in a client-side manager class:

```csharp
private AsyncServerStreamingCall<ServerToClientNotification>? _call;
private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;
```

When I subscribe to the service client-side I set the call object and pass the token source:

```csharp
public async void SubscribeToNotificationService()
{
   _call = _serviceClient.SubscribeToNotifications(...);
   _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   await foreach (var message in responseStream.ReadAllAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token))
   {
       // handle incoming notifications
   }
}
```

And when I want to stop streaming I send the cancellation token and dispose of the call:

```csharp
public void UnsubscribeFromNotificationService()
{
   _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
   _call.Dispose();
}
```

This works fine, but when I want to call the SubscribeNotificationService() again, I get the following exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="Call canceled by the client.")'
```

Same if I just dispose the call and don't send a cancellation:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="gRPC call disposed.")'
```

It seems to me that server-side the service still knows that the call was cancelled / disposed from this client and doesn't let him establish the stream again.

**How can I correctly close and re-establish such a stream at a later point in time?**

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me here. Below is a more detailed version of my code.

---

**Service definition in the protobuf file** (stripped down to relevant parts)

```
service NotificationService {
    rpc SubscribeToNotifications (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream ServerToClientNotification);
}

message ServerToClientNotification {
   ...
}
```

**Server-side service implementation** (stripped down to the relevant parts)

```csharp
public class NotificationService : Server.Protos.NotificationService.NotificationServiceBase
{
    private readonly IServerNotificationManager _notificationManager;

    public NotificationService(IServerNotificationManager notificationManager)
    {
        _notificationManager = notificationManager;
    }

    public override async Task SubscribeToNotifications(Empty request,
        IServerStreamWriter<ServerToClientNotification> responseStream,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        await HandleOutgoingNotificationsAsync(responseStream, context);
    }

    private async Task HandleOutgoingNotificationsAsync(
        IServerStreamWriter<ServerToClientNotification> responseStream,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // send notifications with help of the _notificationManager...
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            // client unsubscribed, I currently do nothing here, maybe I should?
        }
    }
}
```

**Client-side implementation** (stripped down to the relevant parts)

I have a client class that sort of functions a container for the server connection and the manager that subscribes to the service (and other managers...). The server connection gets passed to the notification manager, which uses it to establish the call. This is where I call the subscribe and unsubscribe from:

```csharp
public class Client
{
    private IServerConnection _serverConnection;
    private IClientNotificationManager? _notificationManager;

    public Client(string address, string port, bool useTlsCertificate)
    {
        _serverConnection = new ServerConnection();
        _serverConnection.SetupGrpcChannel(address, port, useTlsCertificate);
    }

    public void SubscribeNotifications()
    {
        if (_notificationManager is null)
        {
            var serviceClient = new NotificationService.NotificationServiceClient(_serverConnection.Channel);
            _notificationManager = new ClientNotificationManager(serviceClient);
        }

        _notificationManager.SubscribeToNotificationService();
    }

    public void UnsubscribeNotifications()
    {
        if (_notificationManager is not null)
        {
            _notificationManager.UnsubscribeFromNotificationService();
            _notificationManager.DisposeCall();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the client-side notification manager, which I already described in the question above:

```csharp
public class ClientNotificationManager : NotificationManager, IClientNotificationManager
{
    private AsyncServerStreamingCall<ServerToClientNotification>? _call;
    private readonly NotificationService.NotificationServiceClient _serviceClient;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;

    public ClientNotificationManager(NotificationService.NotificationServiceClient serviceClient)
    {
        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
    }

    public async void SubscribeToNotificationService()
    {
        _call = _serviceClient.SubscribeToNotifications(new Empty(), headers: new Metadata 
        {
            // passing some metadata here...
        });

        await HandleIncomingNotificationsAsync(_call.ResponseStream);
    }

    private async Task HandleIncomingNotificationsAsync(IAsyncStreamReader<ServerToClientNotification> responseStream)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await foreach (var message in responseStream.ReadAllAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token))
            {
                // handle incoming notifications...
            }
        });
    }

    public void UnsubscribeFromNotificationService()
    {
        if (_call is not null && _cancellationTokenSource is not null)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }

    public void DisposeCall()
    {
        if (_call is not null)
        {
            _call.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So once you cancel a call, you can't "reuse" it. You have to create a new call and use it instead. It seems that your code somehow manages to reuse an already-canceled call (I don't see where it does it, but there is likely some bug somewhere in the code). When you start a new call from a client, there is now way for the server to "remember" that the previous call got cancelled. So either you're reusing an old call object by mistake or you're reusing an already-triggered cancellation token source.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know, I will have a look at my code again and then come back to you. The thing is, that even if I set the entire _notificationManager (which holds the call and cancellation token source) to null after ending a call and creating a new one, I still get the same error (but this should definetly create a new call I think). Anyway, thank you for your reply, I will look at my code again and check if I am somehow reusing the call

Comment: @JanTattermusch I never let my code run after the Exceptions have been thrown, and then it actually runs fine. Here is the pattern I observed: I send a cancellation and close the call, I get no errors -> I wait 5 minutes -> I create a new call and cancellation token source reusing the same already instantiated gRPC channel to the same service -> I then get the exceptions, which still seem to be in the result stream -> after I reveive the exceptions, everything works fine, without any errors

Comment: In short: the exceptions still seem to be in the result stream, which kind of sounds like [this issue I found on github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1920#issuecomment-446107176).  So I close the call, create a new one and the new call immediatly gets the exception from the old call. The question is how do I correctly clean the result stream of exceptions AFTER I send a cancellation token and _call.Dispose() ?

Comment: @dan-kli How did you solve this?

Comment: Ah, I implemented this more than a year ago, so I'm not too sure, but just from looking at the code, it seems like I just filter out this specific exception on the client side (with a try/catch). After all, I only cancel from the client side in my implementation, so I do not need to add any specific code for this exception. This was just a prototype, I do not know how I would properly work around / solve this problem in production code.